# Can't flatten at all (loop tools flatten, cleanup make planar faces, s z z 0), so how can i flatten?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

So googling around I found three ways to flatten

1. Using loop tools, flatten.
2. Using cleanup, make planar faces.
3. Using <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>.

None of them make it flat, the only thing that do something was <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>. It modified the faces slightly, but its still not flat at all.

[Video of the issue in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZb6KVuMzYw)

How do i flatten the ground?

Comment: turns out i can flatten them by entering sculpt mode, and use smooth tool. I wonder why the three methods i mentioned in the OP didnt work.

Comment: It seems that the mesh is already FLAT in that position. can you share the blend file? (remove the part of the mesh you are not interested to flat)

Comment: I thought the same thing. They looked flat to me.